# pyspark How can i get only the max and min values for each parameter_code+county_name

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently using pyspark in a google colab notebook and after doing some data cleaning I finished with a dataframe that has:
parameter code; county name ; arithmetic mean for each day

[image: inicial table]

i need to have a table that gives for each parameter the name of the county with highest value and lowest value

After doing this groupby i ended up getting what i wanted (have for each parameter code and county name the value for the highest value) but only for the max value, i also need for the min value

```
county_param_value_small_grouped_parameter_code = county_param_value_small.groupby('parameter_code','county_name').max('arithmetic_mean').orderBy("parameter_code","max(arithmetic_mean)",ascending=False).show(10)
```

[image: Table with parameter sorted | county name | highest value]

What I wanted to end up with would be a table with 2 county name and 2 values for each parameter code, being highest value and lowest value.
But I am having a lot of trouble manipulating this because it always returns an object, i have to make all the conditions in one go and have a .show() in the end.

Comment: Do you just want to add `min` of `arithmetic_mean` to your current result? could you give a few sample data and expected result for the sample data in plain text?

Comment: final table should be something like this 
parameter_code | county name | value 
88136 | Mahoning | 0.909
88136 | East Baton Rouge | 0.0847
89463 | Galveston | 0.893
89463 | Douglas | 0.002
(...)
(...)
(...)

Because I want to show which counties have the best/worst air quality? (and rank counties considering pollutants’ level!) thats why i need two roows for each polutant level, I am also trying to get a table with max values and a table with min values and somehow make a join, but also having trouble figuring this out
edit: i think when i change line the editor doesn't accept it

Comment: Do not post for table, code and just copy and paste it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to the problem is to use window functions to attach for every row having the same `parameter_code` the `max` and `min` `arithmetic_mean` across the group. Finally filter rows where the `arithmetic_mean` is equal to the `min` or `max` value of the group.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

data = [("1", "IN", 10, ), ("1", "NL", 20, ), ("1", "DE", 15, ), ("2", "US", 100, ), ("2", "BE", 200, ), ("2", "FR", 150, )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("parameter_code", "county_name", "arithmetic_mean", ))

window_spec = W.partitionBy("parameter_code")

df.withColumn("max_arithmetic_mean", F.max("arithmetic_mean").over(window_spec))\
  .withColumn("min_arithmetic_mean", F.min("arithmetic_mean").over(window_spec))\
  .filter((F.col("arithmetic_mean") == F.col("max_arithmetic_mean")) | (F.col("arithmetic_mean") == F.col("min_arithmetic_mean")))\
  .select("parameter_code", "county_name", "arithmetic_mean").show()
```

### Output

```
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
|parameter_code|county_name|arithmetic_mean|
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
|             1|         IN|             10|
|             1|         NL|             20|
|             2|         US|            100|
|             2|         BE|            200|
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
```

Comment: thank you for answering this looks like it should work, but unfortunately its giving me all the parameter code , and giving me all zeros for all the arithmetic mean.

Comment: It's possible that the minimum `arithmetic_mean` in your dataset is `0`. I suggest filtering out the zeros and then apply this logic to verify if this is the reason.

Comment: that is a good point! thank you. im going to try that and i'll comment again

Comment: well turnes out you were right all along, indeed when i droped the zero rows I got the final table i was looking for. thank you snithish